# undefined method `nested_set_options' in active_admin using awesome_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm using awesome_nested_set with activeadmin in rails3, when I override form edit using the following code

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :parent_category
        f.input :url
        f.input :map_id, :as => :select, :collection => nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" },  :input_html => { :class => 'select2'}
    end
f.buttons
end
```

it works like a charm, but when I try to use the same code for filter as follows :

```
filter :category, :as =>:select, :collection => nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" }, :input_html => { :class => 'select2'}
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
undefined method `nested_set_options' for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x007f20c039b0b0>
```

So, what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

I worked with this for 3 hours and found the following solution.

Add this to your activeadmin file:

```
include CollectiveIdea::Acts::NestedSet::Helper
ActiveAdmin.register Company do
```